# python - class fields as types

Tags: python, class, exception, inheritance

In my code I need to make some classes A,B,C inherit from a class X.
Classes A,B,C have their own exceptions (A_exception, B_exception, C_exception) which are raised from within their methods.

```
class A(X):
    def foo(self):
        raise A_exception('A_exception')

class B(X):
    def foo(self):
        raise B_exception('B_exception')

class C(X):
    def foo(self):
        raise C_exception('C_exception')
```

In the above example, how can I avoid to re-writing of the method foo()?
Of course it's better if foo() is defined in class X with a generic exception type, but from A,B,C this generic type should be resolved into the specific type.
Is it possible in Python to associate to a class, e.g. as a field, a specific class type? I've looked for it on internet but didn't find anything...

Comment: So is whatever `X` have a "General Exception" that where by "A", "B", and "C" still mean the same thing, but need to be more specific?

Comment: Your subclasses that purport the same interface probably shouldn't be trying to do something clever that doesn't fit in with the inheritance structure...

Comment: Yes, this is a simple case, but I need to diversify the behavior of A,B,C.

Comment: Then just make each method raise the most appropriate exception? Kinda missing what exactly it is you want to do here I'm guessing...

Comment: What do you want to happen if you do `class D(B, C)` for instance?

Comment: B, C are not intended in my code to be inherited by other classes

Comment: So you want the same method from in the same derived classes to raise *different* exceptions specific to the class - any reason you can't use a base exception class and pass arguments to it that the caller can check?

Comment: Maybe the question should have been more generic and not regarding only exceptions: can a child class contain a class type C_i specific of only that child class? can that class type C_i be used in methods defined by the parent class?

Comment: In Python you can do all kinds of weird and wonderful(?) stuff that'd break static design modules including classes changing at run time. Perhaps the question would better be composed as "I want to do... because..." rather than an issue that isn't actually the issue at hand...

Comment: You're right, but it's not always possible to refactor completely a huge code to satisfy architectural best practices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go one step further, and make each of the `A`, `B`, and `C` exceptions inherit from an `X` exception. That way, code that doesn't care it is catching exceptions from `A.foo`, `B.foo`, or `C.foo` also won't care which specific exception it is catching, as long as it is an `X` exception.

```
class XError(Exception): pass
class AError(XError): pass
class BError(XError): pass
class CError(XError): pass

class X:
    exception = XError
    def foo(self):
        raise self.exception()

class A(X):
    exception = AError

class B(X):
    exception = BError

class C(X):
    exception = CError


for x in [foo, bar, baz]:  # List of instances of X. Could be a mix of As, Bs, and Cs
    try:
        x.foo()
    except XError:  # Will catch AError et al, but not other errors
        # ...
```

---

You might also consider making the exception classes themselves attributes of the main classes.

```
class X:
    class Error(Exception): pass
    def foo(self):
        raise self.Error()

class A(X):
    class Error(X.Error): pass

class B(X):
    class Error(X.Error): pass

class C(X):
    class Error(X.Error): pass

try:
    for x in [foo, bar, baz]:
        x.foo()
except X.Error:  # Will catch A.Error, B.Error, C.Error as well
    # ...
```

This reduces some boilerplate, but some (most?) people may prefer the exceptions to be declared at module scope and have distinct names rather than rely on the fully qualified name.

---

You *might* even go so far as to define a metaclass that will inject an appropriate exception subclass into the class definition automatically; I'll leave that as an exercise unless I get bored later today.

```
class with_exception(type):
    # TODO

class X(metaclass=with_exception):
    def foo(self):
        raise self.Error()

class A(X):
    pass

class B(X):
    pass

class C(X):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
# Modify your parent class 
class X:
    exception = None

    def foo(self):
        raise self.exception

# Define `exception` attribute in inheritor class. It should be an instance of exception
class A(X):
    exception = BaseException('A_exception')
```

Actual behaviour in interactive console:

```
[2] child = A()
[3] child.foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BaseException                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-759019553652> in <module>()
----> 1 child.foo()

<ipython-input-9-54598e612d0a> in foo(self)
      2     exception = None
      3     def foo(self):
----> 4         raise self.exception
      5
      6

BaseException: A_exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Class X:
    Ex= X_exception('Exception')

    foo(self):
        raise self.Ex

Class A(X):
    Ex= A_exception('A')
```

Comment: `raise Ex` — NameError: unknown name 'Ex'.

Comment: Fixed. Need to do self.Ex